# Why are routers not answering ARP Broadcasts?

Tags: router, arp

Host A wants to send something to Host B who is in a different network. Between them is Router 1. Host A sends an ARP broadcast but Router 1 is not answering it. Why is that so?

Comment: Not sure what you mean. Host A would ARP to find the MAC of Router 1 and the router would reply. Host A could then encapsulate the frame and forward it towards the router. Are you saying if Host A sends a broadcast in its subnet why the router does not forward that to Host B?

Comment: if you truly have host a and host b in different networks, could you check their netmasks?  It sounds like the netmask on host a is wrong

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The router will not do this by default, unless you enable [Proxy ARP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proxy_ARP) on that router's interface(s), but best practices dictate Proxy ARP should be disabled wherever possible.

However, host A should know by analyzing its own subnet mask (binary AND against its own subnet mask and Host B's address) that Host B is on a different network, and instead send the traffic to its default gateway (if one is configured), and if necessary, Host A will ARP for its default gateway's MAC address, which the router should respond to when appropriate.